# New grails 2.3.7 app is ignoring <%= %>

Tags: html, grails, escaping

I am writing a new grails 2.3.7 app and I'm trying to use <%= %> to avoid html encoding a domain class field.

For some reason grails is ignoring this and encoding the thing anyway.

As an example

```
<%="<h2>FOO</h2>"%>
```

Just renders as

```
<h2>FOO</h2>
```

and not as a level 2 header as expected.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug but in fact Grails' automatic XSS attack prevention. See http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/security.html#xssPrevention

What you want to do it mark the output as raw:

```
<%=raw("<h2>FOO</h2>")%>
```

However, note that this should be done with extreme care as you may put your application at risk of XSS attacks.